# Mapbox and GWT integration

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, mapbox

I am trying to make the MapBox Javascript Library work with GWT(Google Web Toolkit).

Below is a snippet of the code that i'm using:

```
    HorizontalPanel horizontalPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
    horizontalPanel.setHeight("400px");
    horizontalPanel.setWidth("600px");
    horizontalPanel.getElement().setId("geo-map");

    ScriptInjector.fromUrl("https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.4/mapbox.js").setCallback(new Callback<Void, Exception>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception reason) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void result) {

            ScriptInjector.fromString("$wnd.$(document).ready(function() {" +
                            "console.log(\"Ok, it's me!\");" +
                            "L.mapbox.accessToken = \"Some Acess Token\";" +
                            "var map = L.mapbox.map(\"geo-map\", \"geo-map-id\").setView([40, -74.50], 9);" +
                            "console.log(\"Ok, it's me again!\");" +
                        "});").inject();

        }
    }).inject();

    // Add the nameField and sendButton to the RootPanel
    // Use RootPanel.get() to get the entire body element
    RootPanel.get("nameFieldContainer").add(horizontalPanel);
```

When i run the code, i receive the following exception:

**[15:00:46.146] Error: Map container not found. @ https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.4/mapbox.js:1**

Thanks in Advance

**Update:** I finally make it work, i had to put the javascript function in the end of the body tag of my HTML file of the module.

Comment: i tried your code its running may be you need internet connection to load the url which is not happening, dont know just my guess..

Comment: Hi @SCK, I just checked the internet connection and it's ok. The same error continues to pop up here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GWT 2.8 JsInterop with MapBox GL JS goes like this:

1. Add the css and js on your index page as per  [MapBox Tutorial](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/)
2. Make the mapboxgl.Map available to your Java:

   ```
   @JsType(isNative = true, namespace = "mapboxgl")

    class Map {

       @JsOverlay
       private static long serial = 0L; 

       @JsConstructor
       protected Map(JavaScriptObject options) { }

       @JsOverlay
       public static Map build(AbsolutePanel panel) {
           return Map.build(panel, new JSONObject());
       }

       @JsOverlay
       public static Map build(AbsolutePanel panel, JSONObject mapOptions) {

           String id = "map" + serial++;
           mapOptions.put("container", new JSONString(id));

           panel.getElement().setId(id);
           Map result = new Map(mapOptions.getJavaScriptObject());     
           return result;
       }

   }
   ```
3. Later on you can add other Methods, Properties, Events to your Map class
4. Use the parameter JSONObject mapOptions to set your map properties, for example:

   {
     center: [-122.420679, 37.772537],

   zoom: 13,

   style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9' }
5. Create a class that extends AbsolutePanel to become your Map Widget

   ```
   public class MapPanel extends AbsolutePanel {

   private static boolean accessTokenIsSet = false; 

   Map map;
   JSONObject mapOptions;
   MapPanel instance;

   public MapPanel(int width, int height) {
       this(width, height, new MapOptions());
   }

   public MapPanel(int width, int height, JSONObject mapOptions) {     
       instance = this;
       this.mapOptions = mapOptions;

       if ( !accessTokenIsSet ) {
           setAccessToken();
           accessTokenIsSet = true;
       }

       getElement().getStyle().setWidth(width, Unit.PX);
       getElement().getStyle().setHeight(height, Unit.PX);
       this.addEvents();
   }

   private void addEvents() {
       addAttachHandler(new AttachEvent.Handler() {

           @Override
           public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
               if ( event.isAttached() ) {
                   map = Map.build(instance, mapOptions);
               }

           }
       });
   }

   private static native void setAccessToken() /*-{
       mapboxgl.accessToken = '<your-key>';
   }-*/;
   ```

   }
6. Instantiate your MapPanel widget and add wherever needed

   ```
   JSONObject mapOptions = new JSONObject();

   JSONArray center = new JSONArray();
   center.set(0, new JSONNumber(-122.420679));
   center.set(1, new JSONNumber(37.772537));

   mapOptions.put("style", new JSONString("mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"));
   mapOptions.put("zoom", new JSONNumber(13));
   mapOptions.put("center", center);
   MapPanel mapPanel = new MapPanel(300, 300, mapOptions);
   RootPanel.get().add(mapPanel);
   ```

Comment: Great solution, and a padronized one, thank you @RodrigoFava

Answer (score 2):

FYI: I have been writing a GWT client for the [Mapbox GL JS library](https://github.com/danielfornies/gwt-mapbox-gl).
It still needs to be completed/improved, but you can already use a good part of its features:

Currently [used here](https://mydrive.tomtom.com):